# Problem of checking for empty filter in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset as below:

[image]

I want to check if there's any "invalid" status (which we don't in this image). If there's any, I want to delete  the whole row and if not, I want to keep it the way it is. The code I have for this is:

```
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter 1, "invalid"
    If .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count-1).SpecialCells(xlVisible) is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Invalids"
    Else 
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count-1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

However, my code gave me an error on the line `If .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count-1).SpecialCells(xlVisible) is Nothing Then`, saying that `no cells were found`. I just couldn't figure out what's wrong with this empty-checking if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead...

```
Dim filterRange As Range

With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter 1, "invalid"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set filterRange = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Not filterRange Is Nothing Then
        filterRange.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    .AutoFilter
End With
```